# ANDAND condition should have an 'if true then false'

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am having problems compiling the following code:

```
@Composable
fun getWallethColors()= KotprefSettings.getNightMode().let {
    if ((it == MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM && isSystemInDarkTheme()) || it == MODE_NIGHT_YES)
        darkColors()
    else
        lightColors()
}
```

it throws this error:

```
e: org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.BackendException: Backend Internal error: Exception during IR lowering
File being compiled: /home/ligi/git/walleth/app/app/src/main/java/org/walleth/ui/theme/WallethComposeTheme.kt
The root cause java.lang.AssertionError was thrown at: org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.lower.JvmOptimizationLowering$lower$transformer$1.visitWhen(JvmOptimizationLowering.kt:197)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.CodegenUtil.reportBackendException(CodegenUtil.kt:239)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.CodegenUtil.reportBackendException$default(CodegenUtil.kt:235)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PerformByIrFilePhase.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:124)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PerformByIrFilePhase.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:112)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:94)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompositePhase.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:30)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:94)
w: Flag is not supported by this version of the compiler: -Xallow-jvm-ir-dependencies

    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompilerPhaseKt.invokeToplevel(CompilerPhase.kt:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmLower.lower(JvmLower.kt:407)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.doGenerateFilesInternal(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:191)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.generateModule(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:62)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.compileCorrectFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.generate(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:592)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:212)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:155)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:169)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:88)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:386)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:110)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:303)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:121)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:74)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:607)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1659)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor110.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: ANDAND condition should have an 'if true then false' body on its second branch. Failing expression: WHEN type=kotlin.Boolean origin=ANDAND
  BRANCH
    if: CALL 'public final fun EQEQ (arg0: kotlin.Any?, arg1: kotlin.Any?): kotlin.Boolean declared in kotlin.internal.ir' type=kotlin.Boolean origin=EQEQ
      arg0: GET_VAR 'it: kotlin.Int declared in org.walleth.ui.theme.WallethComposeThemeKt.getWallethColors$lambda-1' type=kotlin.Int origin=null
      arg1: CONST Int type=kotlin.Int value=-1
    then: BLOCK type=kotlin.Boolean origin=null
      BLOCK type=kotlin.Unit origin=null
        CALL 'public abstract fun startReplaceableGroup (key: kotlin.Int): kotlin.Unit declared in androidx.compose.runtime.Composer' type=kotlin.Unit origin=null
          $this: GET_VAR '$$composer: androidx.compose.runtime.Composer? declared in org.walleth.ui.theme.WallethComposeThemeKt.getWallethColors$lambda-1' type=androidx.compose.runtime.Composer? origin=null
          key: CONST Int type=kotlin.Int value=-1635160717
        CALL 'public final fun sourceInformation (composer: androidx.compose.runtime.Composer, sourceInformation: kotlin.String): kotlin.Unit declared in androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerKt' type=kotlin.Unit origin=null
          composer: GET_VAR '$$composer: androidx.compose.runtime.Composer? declared in org.walleth.ui.theme.WallethComposeThemeKt.getWallethColors$lambda-1' type=androidx.compose.runtime.Composer? origin=null
          sourceInformation: CONST String type=kotlin.String value="21@785L21"
      VAR IR_TEMPORARY_VARIABLE name:tmp0_group type:kotlin.Boolean [val]
        CALL 'public final fun isSystemInDarkTheme ($composer: androidx.compose.runtime.Composer?, $changed: kotlin.Int): kotlin.Boolean declared in androidx.compose.foundation.DarkThemeKt' type=kotlin.Boolean origin=null
          $composer: GET_VAR '$$composer: androidx.compose.runtime.Composer? declared in org.walleth.ui.theme.WallethComposeThemeKt.getWallethColors$lambda-1' type=androidx.compose.runtime.Composer? origin=null
          $changed: CONST Int type=kotlin.Int value=0
      CALL 'public abstract fun endReplaceableGroup (): kotlin.Unit declared in androidx.compose.runtime.Composer' type=kotlin.Unit origin=null
        $this: GET_VAR '$$composer: androidx.compose.runtime.Composer? declared in org.walleth.ui.theme.WallethComposeThemeKt.getWallethColors$lambda-1' type=androidx.compose.runtime.Composer? origin=null
      GET_VAR 'val tmp0_group: kotlin.Boolean [val] declared in org.walleth.ui.theme.WallethComposeThemeKt.getWallethColors$lambda-1' type=kotlin.Boolean origin=null
  BRANCH
    if: CONST Boolean type=kotlin.Boolean value=true
    then: BLOCK type=kotlin.Boolean origin=null
      CALL 'public abstract fun startReplaceableGroup (key: kotlin.Int): kotlin.Unit declared in androidx.compose.runtime.Composer' type=kotlin.Unit origin=null
        $this: GET_VAR '$$composer: androidx.compose.runtime.Composer? declared in org.walleth.ui.theme.WallethComposeThemeKt.getWallethColors$lambda-1' type=androidx.compose.runtime.Composer? origin=null
        key: CONST Int type=kotlin.Int value=849626562
      CALL 'public abstract fun endReplaceableGroup (): kotlin.Unit declared in androidx.compose.runtime.Composer' type=kotlin.Unit origin=null
        $this: GET_VAR '$$composer: androidx.compose.runtime.Composer? declared in org.walleth.ui.theme.WallethComposeThemeKt.getWallethColors$lambda-1' type=androidx.compose.runtime.Composer? origin=null
      CONST Boolean type=kotlin.Boolean value=false

    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.lower.JvmOptimizationLowering$lower$transformer$1.visitWhen(JvmOptimizationLowering.kt:197)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.lower.JvmOptimizationLowering$lower$transformer$1.visitWhen(JvmOptimizationLowering.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrWhen.accept(IrWhen.kt:29)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpression.transform(IrExpression.kt:33)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrBranch.transformChildren(IrWhen.kt:54)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformer$DefaultImpls.visitBranch(IrElementTransformer.kt:132)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.lower.JvmOptimizationLowering$lower$transformer$1.visitBranch(JvmOptimizationLowering.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.lower.JvmOptimizationLowering$lower$transformer$1.visitBranch(JvmOptimizationLowering.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrBranchImpl.transform(IrWhenImpl.kt:56)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrWhen.transformChildren(IrWhen.kt:37)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.lower.JvmOptimizationLowering$lower$transformer$1.visitWhen(JvmOptimizationLowering.kt:191)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.lower.JvmOptimizationLowering$lower$transformer$1.visitWhen(JvmOptimizationLowering.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrWhen.accept(IrWhen.kt:29)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpression.transform(IrExpression.kt:33)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrBranch.transformChildren(IrWhen.kt:54)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformer$DefaultImpls.visitBranch(IrElementTransformer.kt:132)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.lower.JvmOptimizationLowering$lower$transformer$1.visitBranch(JvmOptimizationLowering.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.lower.JvmOptimizationLowering$lower$transformer$1.visitBranch(JvmOptimizationLowering.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrBranchImpl.transform(IrWhenImpl.kt:56)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrWhen.transformChildren(IrWhen.kt:37)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.lower.JvmOptimizationLowering$lower$transformer$1.visitWhen(JvmOptimizationLowering.kt:191)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.lower.JvmOptimizationLowering$lower$transformer$1.visitWhen(JvmOptimizationLowering.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrWhen.accept(IrWhen.kt:29)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpression.transform(IrExpression.kt:33)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrVariableImpl.transformChildren(IrVariableImpl.kt:81)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformer$DefaultImpls.visitDeclaration(IrElementTransformer.kt:46)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.lower.JvmOptimizationLowering$lower$transformer$1.visitDeclaration(JvmOptimizationLowering.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.lower.JvmOptimizationLowering$lower$transformer$1.visitDeclaration(JvmOptimizationLowering.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformer$DefaultImpls.visitVariable(IrElementTransformer.kt:60)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.lower.JvmOptimizationLowering$lower$transformer$1.visitVariable(JvmOptimizationLowering.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.lower.JvmOptimizationLowering$lower$transformer$1.visitVariable(JvmOptimizationLowering.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrVariableImpl.accept(IrVariableImpl.kt:74)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.IrElement$DefaultImpls.transform(IrElement.kt:32)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.IrElementBase.transform(IrElementBase.kt:19)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.util.TransformKt.transformInPlace(transform.kt:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrContainerExpression.transformChildren(IrBlock.kt:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.lower.JvmOptimizationLowering$lower$transformer$1.visitContainerExpression(JvmOptimizationLowering.kt:340)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.lower.JvmOptimizationLowering$lower$transformer$1.visitContainerExpression(JvmOptimizationLowering.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformer$DefaultImpls.visitBlock(IrElementTransformer.kt:91)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.lower.JvmOptimizationLowering$lower$transformer$1.visitBlock(JvmOptimizationLowering.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.lower.JvmOptimizationLowering$lower$transformer$1.visitBlock(JvmOptimizationLowering.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrBlockImpl.accept(IrBlockImpl.kt:48)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpression.transform(IrExpression.kt:33)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpression.transform(IrExpression.kt:26)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrBlockBody.transformChildren(IrBody.kt:62)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.lower.JvmOptimizationLowering$lower$transformer$1.visitBlockBody(JvmOptimizationLowering.kt:334)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.lower.JvmOptimizationLowering$lower$transformer$1.visitBlockBody(JvmOptimizationLowering.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrBlockBody.accept(IrBody.kt:54)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrBody.transform(IrBody.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrFunction.transformChildren(IrFunction.kt:69)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.lower.JvmOptimizationLowering$lower$transformer$1.visitFunction(JvmOptimizationLowering.kt:86)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.lower.JvmOptimizationLowering$lower$transformer$1.visitFunction(JvmOptimizationLowering.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformer$DefaultImpls.visitSimpleFunction(IrElementTransformer.kt:53)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.lower.JvmOptimizationLowering$lower$transformer$1.visitSimpleFunction(JvmOptimizationLowering.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.lower.JvmOptimizationLowering$lower$transformer$1.visitSimpleFunction(JvmOptimizationLowering.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrSimpleFunction.accept(IrSimpleFunction.kt:29)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.IrElement$DefaultImpls.transform(IrElement.kt:32)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.IrElementBase.transform(IrElementBase.kt:19)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.util.TransformKt.transformInPlace(transform.kt:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrClass.transformChildren(IrClass.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.lower.JvmOptimizationLowering$lower$transformer$1.visitClass(JvmOptimizationLowering.kt:74)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.lower.JvmOptimizationLowering$lower$transformer$1.visitClass(JvmOptimizationLowering.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrClass.accept(IrClass.kt:56)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.IrElement$DefaultImpls.transform(IrElement.kt:32)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.IrElementBase.transform(IrElementBase.kt:19)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrFileImpl.transformChildren(IrFileImpl.kt:71)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.lower.JvmOptimizationLowering.lower(JvmOptimizationLowering.kt:355)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.FileLoweringPhaseAdapter.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:155)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.FileLoweringPhaseAdapter.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:151)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:94)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PerformByIrFilePhase.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:121)
    ... 41 more
```

Interestingly when I rewrite it as:

```
fun getWallethColors(isSystemDark: Boolean) = KotprefSettings.getNightMode().let {
    if ((it == MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM && isSystemDark) || it == MODE_NIGHT_YES)
        darkColors()
    else
        lightColors() 
}

@Composable
fun getWallethColors() = getWallethColors(isSystemInDarkTheme())
```

it compiles fine. I am new to jetpack compose - wondering if I am doing something wrong or if this is a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug.  Please file at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128

If the compiler ever throws: `e: org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.BackendException: Backend Internal error`, it is (by definition) always a compiler-level bug.

Comment: thanks & done: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/193550385